# How should I test Rails Enums?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, testing, enums, rails-activerecord

Suppose I have a model called CreditCard. Due to some technical restrictions, it's best if the card networks are represented as an enum. My code looks something like this:

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
   enum network: [:visa, :mastercard, :amex]
end
```

What should be tested when using enums if anything?

Comment: I have the same question also

Answer (score 10, accepted):

If you use an array, you need to make sure the order will be kept:

```
class CreditCard < ActiveRecord::Base
  enum network: %i[visa mastercard amex]
end

RSpec.describe CreditCard, '#status' do
  let!(:network) { %i[visa mastercard amex] }

  it 'has the right index' do
    network.each_with_index do |item, index|
      expect(described_class.statuses[item]).to eq index
    end
  end
end
```

If you use Hash the order does not matter, but the value of each key does. So, it's good to make sure that each key has the equivalent value.

Answer (score 1):

According to Rails doc for [Enum](http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.1.0/classes/ActiveRecord/Enum.html) every value of the array correspond to an integer. I'm guessing you want to test that the network array always keeps its same order. If you're using rspec, you can do something like:

```
describe 'CreditCard' do
  let(:network_values) do
    { visa: 0,
      master: 1
      # etc
    }
  end
  subject { described_class.new }

  it 'has valid a network' do 
    network_values.each do |type, value|
      subject.network = value
      subject.save 
      expect(subject.network).to eql(type.to_s)
    end 
  end 
end
```

*ps: I'm writing from my mobile phone maybe you'll need some tweaking to run*

Comment: I don't love this solution because it just tests what Rails is already testing. However, you have sufficiently answered my question and there maybe nothing to test at all :).

Comment: Yeah, I agree with you. I think that maybe you don't need to test that at all and only test more complex parts.